# What is wrong with my trains code?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MINUTES_PER_HOUR 60

int main(void){

    double distance, vel1, vel2;
    double min_to_meet;
    int hr_to_meet;

    printf("enter the distance separating the trains?\n");
    scanf("%1f", &distance);

    printf("what is the speed of train 1?\n");
    scanf("%1f, &vel1");

    printf("what is the speed of train 2?\n");
    scanf("%1f, &vel2");

    hr_to_meet = distance/(vel1 + vel2);
    min_to_meet = hr_to_meet*MINUTES_PER_HOUR;

    printf("it will take %.31f minutes to meet.\n", min_to_meet);

    printf("the first train will travel %.21f miles.\n", vel1*hr_to_meet);
    printf("the second train will travel %.21f miles.\n", vel2*hr_to_meet);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting zero as my answer can anyone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: what input are you entering?

Comment: your seccond and third scanf is messed up .

Comment: also I think inside all 3 scanfs should be %lf isnt it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

float vs. double:

```
scanf("%f",...)  /* must take the address of a float variable. */

scanf("%lf",...) /* must take the address of a double variable. */
```

So either change your variable type from double to float, or change `%f` to `%lf`.

Note: in `%lf`, the second character is a lower-case L (and not the digit 1, in case you were wondering).

Answer (score 6):

You are calling `scanf` like this

```
 scanf("%1f, &vel2");
```

but I think you want

```
 scanf("%lf", &vel2);
         ^  
         ^
```

and likewise for `vel1`. You also need

```
 scanf("%lf", &distance);
         ^
         ^
```

Not the subtle difference between `"%lf"` (which should be used to scan as a `double` - which your variables are) and what you currently use `"%1f"` to pass as first argument to `scanf`.

The way you are calling `scanf` currently will result in `vel1` and `vel2` remaining uninitialised because you have the quotes in the wrong place. Your quotes are in the right place for `distance` but you have not carried this forward in the `scanf` calls for `vel1` and `vel21. This makes your calculations for`hr_to_meet` incorrect.

Comment: i think you want -> i know you want

Comment: @starrify Thanks - I thought I had actually used `l` instead of `1`. Looks so similar.

Comment: ...and likewise for `distance` :D

Answer (score 4):

fix your scanf from:
`scanf("%1f, &vel2");`
`scanf("%1f, &vel1");`
NOTE:The above code will compile,but it won't assign anything in to the vel1 and vel2 since they are a part of the string that is inside the `scanf`

to:

```
scanf("%lf", &vel1);
scanf("%lf", &vel2);
```

This will compile and assign the scanned variables into vel1 and vel2.

also you maybe mentioned to assign doubles:

```
scanf("%1f", &distance);//takes float
scanf("%lf", &distance);//takes long float which is double
```

Comment: Thanks haccks :) I messed up with syntax on the site :)

Comment: I gave a upvote because this is the _only_ answer that fixes out both the two mistakes. However as an answer, don't you think it would be better to tell the OP _why_ while telling him _how_?

Comment: @starrify If there is something to add feel free to edit